# getting "make" to work on my Windows command line like it does on my unix one

Tags: windows, command-line, compile, make

I want to be able to just type `make` in an appropriate folder and have it work and compile just like it does when I do it in my favorite linux distro.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) will provide you everything you need to compile in a familiar environment on Windows including gcc, make and many common development libraries.  It will even give a Bash shell you can run everything from.  Check out the [Quick Start Guide for Unix](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-ex-unix.html) for some more help.

Comment: I have the cygwin shell; `make` doesn't seem to work when I try it :(

Comment: @Justin: What do you mean by “doesn't seem to work”? Do you get any error message? What does your makefile contain, and are all the required files present?

Comment: @gilles it says `make` is an unrecognized command

Comment: @Justin: then run the cygwin installer (`setup.exe`) again and install more packages, including `make` and whatever other development tools you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[AndLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/), native linux (ubuntu) on your Windows installation, much like Wine for Linux handles Windows.

EDIT: its not really a "windows" command line, but a command line in windows, so depending on what you actually want it for, it may or may not be sufficient.